# How to get IP address from controller's hosts file in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am having difficulty figuring out to set a fact in my Ansible playbook that contains the IP address of a server that is listed in the /etc/hosts file on my controller.  I am running a playbook against my web server which needs the IP address of my file server.  I run the command like this:

```
ansible-playbook deploy-webservers.yml -i inventory.ini -l webservers
```

My inventory file looks like this:

```
[fileservers]
prod-fs1.example.com

[webservers]
prod-web1.example.com

[localhost]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local ansible_python_interpreter=/Users/jsmith/.virtualenvs/provision/bin/python
```

Here is the playbook:

```
---
hosts: all
gather_facts: yes
become: yes


pre_tasks:
  - name: get file server's IP address
    command: "grep prod-fs1 /etc/hosts | awk '{ print $1 }'"
    register: fs_ip_addr
    delegate_to: localhost

  - debug: var={{ fs_ip_addr }}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
TASK [get file server's IP address] ****************************************************************************************
fatal: [prod-web1.example.com -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["grep", "prod-fs1", "/etc/hosts", "|", "awk", "{ print $0 }"], "delta": "0:00:00.010303", "end": "2020-03-03 12:24:36.207656", 
"msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2020-03-03 12:24:36.197353", "stderr": "grep: |: No such file or directory\ngrep: awk: No such file or directory\ngrep: { print $0 }: 
No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["grep: |: No such file or directory", "grep: awk: No such file or directory", "grep: { print $0 }: No such file or directory"], "stdout": "/etc/hosts:45.79.99.99    prod-fs1.example.com    prod-fs1", "stdout_lines": ["/etc/hosts:45.79.99.99    prod-fs1.example.com    prod-fs1"]}


PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************
prod-web1.example.com : ok=7    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0;
```

It looks like Ansible has a problem parsing the command when it reaches the pipe symbol.  Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: Try `shell` instead of `command`.

Comment: You will also need to change `var={{ fs_ip_addr }}` to `var=fs_ip_addr`.

Comment: @Jack You're correct about that. I often forget that you can't use braces with "var=".  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. No need to delegate to localhost. `lookup` is running always on the controller

```
    - set_fact:
        fs_ip_addr: "{{ (lookup('file', '/etc/hosts').splitlines()|
                         list|
                         select('search', search_host)|
                         list|
                         first).split().0 }}"
      vars:
        search_host: "prod-fs1"
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution as I've not used "lookup" before.  But it is producing an error: "The task includes an option with an undefined variable.  The error was: No first item, sequence was empty."  I will break this down and see if I can figure out what is causing this error.

Comment: Right. Try to display the results step by step. The task is working for me (with changed search_host).

Comment: Yes, you're right.  search_host was incorrect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified a bit.  Note that search_host is a var.

```
- set_fact:
        fs_ip_addr: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/hosts').splitlines() |
                      select('search', search_host) |
                      first | split() | first }}"
```